# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/db

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have seen this error popping up many times. I have searched the web and tried stuff like adding the mysql-connector file to the buildpath, but nothing worked out for me.

This Code works when running with spigot, this is only another Linux user and not spigot.

Im running this Code in a plugin for the JTSServermod for TS3 on a Linux Debian with Java 8.

The full error message is:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/db
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at net.mysticsouls.TeamSpeakBot.utils.NameUUIDUtils.connect(NameUUIDUtils.java:31)
    at net.mysticsouls.TeamSpeakBot.utils.Updater.start(Updater.java:11)
    at net.mysticsouls.TeamSpeakBot.TeamSpeakBot.activate(TeamSpeakBot.java:45)
    at de.stefan1200.jts3servermod.JTS3ServerMod.e(Unknown Source)
    at de.stefan1200.jts3servermod.JTS3ServerMod.b(Unknown Source)
    at de.stefan1200.jts3servermod.i.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And my Code calling it is:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.UUID;

public class NameUUIDUtils {

    private static final String host = "localhost";
    private static final String port = "3307";
    private static final String database = "db";
    private static final String username = "username";
    private static final String password = "*********";
    private static Connection connection;

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        return connection;
    }

    public static boolean isConnected() {
        return connection != null;
    }

    public static void connect() {
        if (!isConnected()) {
            try {
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + database, username,
                        password);
                System.out.println("[NameUUID] MySQL connected!");
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("[NameUUID] MySQL failed to connect!");
            }
        }

        if (isConnected()) {
            try {
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = getConnection().prepareStatement(
                        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CoinSystem (Spielername VARCHAR(100), UUID VARCHAR(100), Coins INT(100), Strafpunkte INT(100))");
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                preparedStatement.close();
                System.out.println("[NameUUID] MySQL Table created!");
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.out.println("[NameUUID] MySQL Table failed to create!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong.

Comment: My guess is that your driver is not available when you run your actual code.  Maybe update your question and tell us your build process.

Comment: Is it possible that your mysql connector file is not up to date?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen what do you mean by that? And how would i make it available.

Comment: Check the duplicate links.  This question often gets asked several times per day.  You need to do your own research before posting a question.

Comment: @AlexanderHeim i downloaded the newest file available!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i checked before and reinstalled the Driver about three times and added it to the .bashrc file etc. but it didnt help

Comment: That may not be the issue, the problem is that _Java_ can't find that JAR at runtime.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen But why? I installed it properly